# QTP script run in remote machine when no user is logged in

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I have created a schedule task to run QTP script . It runs fine when the user is logged in. But when the user gets logged off then task runs but QTP does not start.

Answer (score 1):

QTP requires an interactive desktop session to run properly.  Not only do you have to be logged in, the machine needs to be unlocked.

Comment: Also use caffeine.exe to make sure your computer does not lock or go to sleep. Find it here: http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/index.html#download

Answer (score 1):

This feature exists from UFT 11.53
To enable this, configure the Allow UFT to continue running GUI or business process tests after disconnecting from an RDP computer option in the Run Sessions pane of the Options dialog box.